# Proof that $R_u(v)=v-2\langle v,u\rangle u$ is an isometry on $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: metric-spaces, isometry

Fix  a  unit  vector  $u$  in   $\mathbb R^n$.  Define  $R_u(v)=v-2\langle v,u\rangle u$ .  Show  that  $R_u$  is  an  isometry .

And  then  this  picture  is  given  as  help .
[image]

Please  help  , I  cannot  understand  anything  here .

Comment: Do you know what is isometry ?

Answer (score 2):

Hint : show that $R_u$ preserves scalar products, i.e. $\langle R_u(v),R_u(v')\rangle =\langle v,v'\rangle$ for any $v,v'$. This is an algebraic computation.

Comment: isn't is also necessary that this map is a bijection ?

Comment: @Svetoslav Bijectivity follows from the algebraic property. If $R_u(x)=R_u(y)$, then $0=<R_u(x-y),R_u(x-y)>=<x-y,x-y>$ so $x=y$